# CS-Cart feature values on the list pages

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

In CS-Cart how can I get separate feature values in the list views?
In the detail view you can get any feature that is available by doing something like this:

```
{$product.header_features.1.value}
```

But in the list views it seems the only way to get features is like this:

```
{assign var="product_features" value="product_features_`$obj_id`"}
{$smarty.capture.$product_features nofilter}
```

Which results in a comma separated list wrapped in a div. If the feature is a number it means you end up with a meaningless list of numbers without labels.

Is there any way to have each feature available to the template, so I can add icons before each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With much investigation I finally found that the line:

```
{assign var="product_features" value="product_features_`$obj_id`"}
```

is getting it's information from the file `templates/common/product_data.tpl`

Looking at that file clearly shows it get features from the file `views/products/components/product_features_short_list.tpl`

Then to identify each feature all I needed to do was add a wrap in the foreach like this:

```
<span class="grid-feature feature_{$feature.description|lower|replace:' ':'-' nofilter}"></span>
```

and CSS can do the rest.